# Unable to access Docker container from outside of Linux box

Tags: docker

I've my container up and running, and mapped port 38080 to 8080.
I can access 38080 from inside of the server, but failed from outside of the server.

```
$ sudo docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                       COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                                         NAMES
05a86766464d   dzikoysk/reposilite:3.4.3   "/bin/sh entrypoint.…"   45 minutes ago   Up 23 minutes   0.0.0.0:38080->8080/tcp, :::38080->8080/tcp   reposilite
```

I can access 38080 from the Linux server where docker run (10.0.0.122 is the IP of Linux server).

```
curl http://10.0.0.122:38080 -v > /dev/null
*   Trying 10.0.0.122:38080...
  ...
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

But "Operation timed out" from outside of this host(for example, my laptop):

```
curl http://10.0.0.122:38080 -v > /dev/null
...
* Failed to connect to 10.0.0.122 port 38080 after 75013 ms: Operation timed out
```

The 38080 is indeed listening.

```
$ sudo ss -tunpl |grep 38080
tcp   LISTEN 0      4096                           0.0.0.0:38080      0.0.0.0:*    users:(("docker-proxy",pid=16118,fd=4))  
tcp   LISTEN 0      4096                              [::]:38080         [::]:*    users:(("docker-proxy",pid=16125,fd=4))
```

And firewall is disabled

```
sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
```

I also tried to start up a test server via Python `python3.10 -m http.server 38081`, and access from my laptop.

```
curl http://10.0.0.122:38081 -v > /dev/null
*   Trying 10.0.0.122:38081...
* Connected to 10.0.0.122 (10.0.0.122) port 38081 (#0)
< HTTP/1.0 200 OK
```

Which proved the network bewteen my laptop and Linux host is definitely ok.

And below is what iptable look like:

```
sudo iptables -S
# Warning: iptables-legacy tables present, use iptables-legacy to see them
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD DROP
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N DOCKER
-N DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
-N DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-N DOCKER-USER
-A INPUT -i docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-USER
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o docker0 -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN
```

Thanks advance for your help : )